# DOMContentLoaded vs local script

Tags: html, events, dom

What is the difference between a script called by DOMContentLoaded event handler and a script called at the end of the body ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Obviously, they execute in slightly different context - the inline script is "top-level" code, the DOMContentLoaded handler is in an event listener function.
- Perhaps also obviously, DOMContentLoaded is executed some time after the last inline script. See [HTML5 specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-end.html#the-end) for the list of steps supposed to happen in between.
- DOMContentLoaded is useful in cases when you don't control the markup, e.g. library code or something like browser extensions (See also [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Separation_of_behavior_from_markup))